# python setup.py install SyntaxError: invalid syntax 926

Tags: python, centos5, setup.py, mod-pywebsocket

i'm trying to install "mod_pywebsocket" on CentOS 5.9 32 bit, by following this guide "https://code.google.com/p/websocket-sample/wiki/HowToInstallMod_pywebsocket"

But with the command "sudo python setup.py install" i see an error:

```
[root@localhost src]# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_pywebsocket/mux.py to mux.pyc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/mod_pywebsocket/mux.py", line 926
    finally:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[root@localhost src]#
```

Here some lines of "mux.py" file:

```
916   Writing data will block the worker so we need to release
                # _send_condition before writing.
                self._logger.debug('Sending inner frame: %r' % inner_frame)
                self._request.connection.write(inner_frame)
                write_position += write_length

                opcode = common.OPCODE_CONTINUATION

        except ValueError, e:
            raise BadOperationException(e)
926     finally:
            self._write_inner_frame_semaphore.release()

    def replenish_send_quota(self, send_quota):
        """Replenish send quota."""

        try:
            self._send_condition.acquire()
            if self._send_quota + send_quota > 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:
                self._send_quota = 0
                raise LogicalChannelError(
```

What does it mean? What i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the syntax used in `mux.py` does not work in Python 2.4.  As noted in the current [Python 2 Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> Changed in version 2.5: In previous versions of Python,
>   `try...except...finally` did not work. `try...except` had to be nested in
>   `try...finally`.

My guess is that the code here in `mod_pywebsockets` has changed since the `HowTo` was last tested with Python 2.4 on CentOS.  You could look at patching the code to avoid the `try...except...finally` or search back through the `mod_pywebsockets` code repo to find an earlier version that does work with Python 2.4, or you could install and use a newer version of Python 2 (Python 2.7.5 is current) alongside the system Python 2.4.